# MonoDevelop is not generating IB outlets for my MonoMac project

Tags: interface-builder, monodevelop, monomac

I am getting back in to MonoMac, and straight away, experiencing problems.

I have added my outlets and actions to my XIB files, and linked them with IB controls, saved my XIB, and returned to MonoMac, and it is not regenerating the C# files, so the bindings are not linked - I cannot use them.

What happening? I am using the latest stable versions of everything (MonoMac did all its updates).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes. I you are using a XIB file generated by MonoMac as default resources, you just need to close both MonoDevelop and Xcode, go to your project folder and clear the bin and object folders. Run the MonoMac, double click your XIB file, edit it in Xcode, press the Command+S buttons 2 or 3 times to make sure the files get changed so MonoDevelop will sync them, and your C# files will get generated...
But I had a situation that this didn't work and I couldn't figure it out and that was when I started an Empty MonoMac Project and added an Empty XIB file to it! The C# files do not get Sync after 5 tries and I didn't waste my time trying to fix it. Created a Document MonoMac project, deleted unneeded files and continued my work.
Hope it helps.